# Ubuntu 16.04 halts during shutdown UNLESS I restart systemd prior to shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, systemd

After years without issues on my Ubuntu 16.04, I have had this issue, where shutting my computer down would lead to my computer halting on a screen like the one in the picture below (revealed by pressing ESC).
[image]

HOWEVER, after some experimenting, I found out that by typing in a terminal and executing the command
 `systemctl daemon-reexec`
prior to invoking the shut down, the system would fast and surely shut down properly.
Could someone help me out to pinpont the cause of such behaviour?
Thank you in advance, and wishes of a merry Christmas

Comment: I  admit to not fully understand your suggestion, as I don't know exactly how that would interfere with systemd or the boot process

Comment: however, fsck seems not to be requiring super user permissions on my system, this is the output of the command https://pastebin.com/W6GWdXfD

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, it did not work https://m.imgur.com/oRzkXa0

Answer (score 1):

### systemd - Failed unmounting `/boot/efi`

The closest error I can find to this is from Arch Linux: [[SOLVED] Failed unmount temporary directory on shutdown](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228151)

The solution there is to tell `systemd` to unmount the temporary directory and see what error messages occur.

To see the current status first use:

```
$ systemctl status /boot/efi
● boot-efi.mount - /boot/efi
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Sun 2018-12-30 15:01:14 MST; 1 day 3h ago
    Where: /boot/efi
     What: /dev/nvme0n1p2
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 910 ExecMount=/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/D656-F2A8 /boot/efi -t vfat -o umask=

Dec 30 15:01:14 alien systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Dec 30 15:01:14 alien systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
```

Save all your work first and use:

```
$ systemctl stop /boot/efi
```

A dialog box will appear requesting your password.

For myself I received no errors and then used:

```
$ systemctl status /boot/efi
● boot-efi.mount - /boot/efi
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-12-31 18:27:53 MST; 3s ago
    Where: /boot/efi
     What: /dev/disk/by-uuid/D656-F2A8
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 21384 ExecUnmount=/bin/umount /boot/efi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20627 ExecMount=/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/D656-F2A8 /boot/efi -t vfat -o umas

Dec 30 15:01:14 alien systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Dec 30 15:01:14 alien systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
Dec 31 18:27:53 alien systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot/efi...
Dec 31 18:27:53 alien systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
```

Finally to return system to normal state use:

```
$ systemctl start /boot/efi
```

In your case hopefully some error messages will occur when unmounting `/boot/efi`.